# I have two input text box and one button, I want to click on button than switch one text box contain to other text box

Tags: java, jsf

I have two input text box and one button, I want to click on button than switch one text box contain to other text box in jsf

Comment: ok, what have you already tried?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the functional requirement. "contain to"? Please elaborate. Also, are you using JSF 1.x or 2.x? Mentioning the JSF version is very important since JSF 2.0 has builtin Ajax support while JSF 1.x hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

write a javascript for transferring the content from one textbox to another textbox. 
Trigger the script on the button "onclick" event. 
Try a code on your own. If you have any troubles, i can help you..!!!